# How to process a short description using NLP

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp

I have a new upcoming requirement, where we have to process, a given description, in a transaction and process that, to break into pre-defined categories.

The description is a description of doctor prescription.

For example *"Take 1 pill every morning for 30 days"*, *"take 1 capsule twice a day for two weeks"*

Note these description have to be broken down into categories say for eg. *days*, *duration*, *repetition*, *type of drug*, *way of taking*.

I am trying to use apache ONLP.

Please suggest how to move forward in this problem, so as to make this more accurate, as the solution has to be accurate.

Comment: Try ONLP. See if it fits your use case

Comment: can I create tree pattern from the test or dummy data that I have and then try to identify all types of pattern over the given data. So as to process

Answer (score 2):

Use Illinois quantities package for standardizing numerical values: http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/demo/quantities/index.php

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do, is called Information Extraction in Computational Linguistics terms. You can consult [this](http://ai.cs.washington.edu/projects/open-information-extraction) page for starters.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out `cTAKES`, an open source project. They are doing the same thing what you want.
You can use `Finite State Machine` for this purpose.
Refer [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CTAKES/cTAKES+3.0+User+Install+Guide) guide, to set up this `cTAKES` project.
Also refer [this](http://ctakes.apache.org/apidocs/3.1.1/ctakes-drug-ner/) javaDoc for frequency unit of Drug.